# Is there a simple way to change colors of a site with bootstrap theme?

Tags: theming

I'm migrating from drupal 7 to drupal 8.
I'm visually empaired, so, a friend helped me to set colors on drupal 7 with bartic theme and color module.
For my new drupal 8 web site, I want to use bootstrap theme, 'cause is more accessible.
I saved colors code in a .txt file and want to set for my bootstrap theme.
I know I have to use sass for colors, but my firend can't preview the result.
I'm wondering if there is a way to preview color before inserting them in bootstrap theme: a module, for example, similar to color module.
Can someone help me?